# Getting an error because I'm using TSetupForm in Inno Setup Compiler Code

Tags: compiler-errors, inno-setup, pascal

I setup the variable `TSetupform` but I'm getting an error using `CenterInsideControl` telling me it's unknown. Isn't `CenterInsideControl` a command `TSetupform`? Also is there something not setup correctly?

```pascal
function SQLServerUserPwd_CreatePage(): Integer;
var
  SqlServerUsrPwdPage: TSetupForm;  
  Label1: TLabel;
  Label2: TLabel;
  Label3: TLabel;
  Page : TWizardPage;
  OKButton : TNewButton;
  CancelButton : TNewButton;
begin

  SqlServerUsrPwdPage := CreateCustomForm();
  SqlServerUsrPwdPage.ClientWidth := ScaleX(400);
  SqlServerUsrPwdPage.ClientHeight := ScaleY(280);
  SqlServerUsrPwdPage.Caption := CustomMessage('SqlserverUserNamePwdPageTitle');
  SqlServerUsrPwdPage.CenterInsideControl(WizardForm, False);

  Label3 := TLabel.Create(SqlServerUsrPwdPage);
  with Label3 do
  begin
    Parent := SqlServerUsrPwdPage;
    Caption := CustomMessage('SqlserverUserNamePwdPageTitleDesc')
    Left := ScaleX(16);
    Top := ScaleY(10);
    Width := ScaleX(377);
    Height := ScaleY(33);
    WordWrap := True;
  end;

end;
```

Here the error message I'm getting.
[image]

I can't find the correct issue online.

Comment: There's no `CenterInsideControl` in https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptclasses – This seems to be [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/218578). What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the documentation for [`TSetupForm`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_scriptclasses.htm#TSetupForm):

```pascal
TSetupForm = class(TUIStateForm)
  function CalculateButtonWidth(const ButtonCaptions: array of String): Integer;
  function ShouldSizeX: Boolean;
  function ShouldSizeY: Boolean;
  procedure FlipSizeAndCenterIfNeeded(const ACenterInsideControl: Boolean; const CenterInsideControlCtl: TWinControl; const CenterInsideControlInsideClientArea: Boolean);
  property ControlsFlipped: Boolean; read;
  property FlipControlsOnShow: Boolean; read write;
  property KeepSizeY: Boolean; read; write;
  property RightToLeft: Boolean; read;
  property SizeAndCenterOnShow: Boolean; read write;
end;
```

There is no `CenterInsideControl` function. But, in [GitHub](https://github.com/jrsoftware/issrc/blob/main/Projects/SetupForm.pas) I do see:

```pascal
procedure SizeAndCenterIfNeeded(const ACenterInsideControl: Boolean;
  const CenterInsideControlCtl: TWinControl;
  const CenterInsideControlInsideClientArea: Boolean);
```

But this function is `protected`.

Comment: Thanks for the insight, Andrew! I'm new to working with Inno scripts and Pascal so this will be very helpful.